# Creating a spesific variable onto the GPU using matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm trying to create a simple variable on the gpu, using

```
a=parallel.gpu.GPUArray.[1 2 3 4 5]
```

The matlab returns

> Error:unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

I know I can create a random variable using the same command :

```
a=parallel.gpu.GPUArray.rand(5)
```

I'm using MATLAB 2012a

Answer (score 1):

To create GPU array you have to use `gpuArray` function:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
gpuX = gpuArray(x);
```

Lets check it:

```
whos gpuX
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class       Attributes

  gpuX      1x5                 4  gpuArray
```

You can read article about using gpu in MATLAB 2012 [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/02/06/using-gpus-in-matlab/).